# Disabling notifications in Asus Transformer

Tags: android

How can I disable notifications in Asus Transformer?
Is there a way to disable notifications only when I turn the device on (from sleep/suspend mode etc.) but to enable them only while working on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can disable notifications from applications you don't to be notify.
Settings > Applications > 'Application Name' > disable checkbox.
I don't know an other way to disable notifications.
Hope it helped.

Comment: @user2517096 You should accept the answer if it helped. So that other Googler also get benefit of it.